# Calculating the value of a formula without duplication, using LuaTeX or similar

Tags: equations, luatex, calculations

If I have a numerical equation (i.e. no unknowns) in LaTeX, is it possible to have the equation typeset and evaluated in one go?

[image: equation showing expanded and calculated forms]

I know calculations can be done relatively easily by embedding Lua code using LuaTeX, but this requires re-writing the equation. A solution would also have to cope with very small and large numbers, so I believe this is outside the scope of normal TeX.

It just seems silly to define a formula in LaTeX and then have to write it again in a linear format in order to compute its value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the two nice answers of @marmot and @Mico did not at all address the main query (to code only once and get both the typesetting and the value) (see the answer by @JosephWright), I feel at liberty to add one more answer not addressing the request, but doing the computation with `xfp`.

(*but see update at bottom for a `\printandeval`*)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N = \frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}
  =\num[scientific-notation=true,
        round-mode=figures,
        round-precision=4]{\fpeval{19.32*1*10^6*6.023*10^23/197}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did not know how to instruct `\fpeval` to output in scientific notation (with a given number of places), but the options of `\num` came to the rescue.

I will also mention `xintexpr` (as I authored it) despite the fact that I still have to add math functions to it (only `sqrt` currently is available). Now, its syntax `\xintthefloatexpr...\relax` causes issues with the way the `siunitx` `\num` parses its argument. One did not get into such problem with `\fpeval` because `\fpeval` uses braces. So let's just add one user interface macro to use braces too, and this makes `\num` happy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
% make \num of siunitx happy, let xintexpr do the rounding to 4 digits
% of float precision (after having computed with 16 digits of
% precision, per default)
% #1 = final precision for printing, #2 = expression to evaluate
\newcommand\floatround[2]{\xintthefloatexpr [#1]#2\relax}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N = \frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}
  =\num{\floatround{4}{19.32*1*10^6*6.023*10^23/197}}
% one can also use ** in place of ^ for powers
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally package [`numprint`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint) has much to recommend to print numbers according to language of document. And its `\numprint` macro (or `\np` with package option `np`) will accept directly the `\xintthefloatexpr` with no hiding within braces contrarily to `\num` of siunitx.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage[np, autolanguage]{numprint}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N = \frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}
  =\np{\xintthefloatexpr [4] 19.32*1*10^6*6.023*10^23/197\relax}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In the simple example considered here one can do like this:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage[np, autolanguage]{numprint}

\newcommand\printandeval[1]{#1=\begingroup
    \def\frac##1##2{(##1)/(##2)}%
    \def\times{*}%
    % etc...
    \edef\x{{\xintthefloatexpr[4]#1\relax}}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\np\x
}

% (in the above we need to re-enact standard meaning of things
%  such as \times, before \np does the typesetting of the value,
%  this is the reason for the `\expandafter` chain.

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N = \printandeval{\frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not try here to provide a completely general one, but in pratice adding a few more redefinitions will cover many test cases, possibly enough for real life usage.

*notice that braces in the input for typesetting did not have to be replaced by parentheses before evaluation (cf `10^{23}`)*

Here is with `xfp` + `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\printandeval[1]{#1=\begingroup
    \def\frac##1##2{(##1)/(##2)}%
    \def\times{*}%
    % etc...
    \edef\x{[scientific-notation=true,
             round-mode=figures,
             round-precision=4]{\fpeval{#1}}}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\num\x
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N = \printandeval{\frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Same output.

The code above can be slightly more efficient with

`\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\np{\xintthefloatexpr[4]#1\relax}}%
    \x`

in the `numprint+xintexpr` case and

`\edef\x{\endgroup\num[scientific-notation=true,
             round-mode=figures,
             round-precision=4]{\fpeval{#1}}}%
    \x`

in the `siunitx+xfp` case.

<sub>thanks to @egreg for chasing `\expandafter`'s and pointing out `\num` is `\protected` and giving me opportunity in this edit to discover new ways to mark-up multi-line code... (I am too much active on github)</sub>

Comment: I know "thanks" comments are not recommended, but I had to say this is a remarkable response. Thank you and all the others on this thread for working to arrive at this.

Comment: @O.MS thanks are welcome... my recommendation is to use `xfp`, you only need to add `\def\sin{sin}`, `\def\cos{cos}`. Brief testing shows that `xfp` will handle `sin 1.57` fine with no need to use parentheses. With `xintexpr` even if in future it has `sin, cos, log, ...` parentheses will surely remain mandatory. On the other hand if you want more than 16 digits of precision or computations with big integers, `xintexpr` know that.

Comment: @O.MS if I try `\fpeval{sin(pi)}` and `\fpeval{sin(pi/1)}` I get in both cases the same small non-zero value, of the order `2e-16`. ( I used `\num[scientific-notation=true]{\fpeval{sin(pi)}}`, `\num[scientific-notation=true]{\fpeval{sin(pi/1)}}`). I am not sure why you get two distinct values. As per achieving `sin(pi)=0` with `xfp`, I found in  `source3.pdf` page 196 the comment that `sin(8pi)` is not quite zero.

Comment: To fix this you probably only need to round first to fixed point, `\num[scientific-notation=true, round-mode=figures, round-precision=4]{\fpeval{round(sin(pi/1),15)}}` first rounds to 15 digits of fixed point precision via `xfp` services, and then `siunitx` again rounds but to 4 digits floating point. The result is `0` as expected.

Comment: Amazing! it's working really well now, good enough for what I need. I had a quick look and Lua doesn't offer any more precision than using `xfp` so this is perfect.  Once again thanks.

Comment: @O.MS `xfp`'s main author is @BrunoLeFloch as part of his contributions to LaTeX3.

Comment: `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\num[<same options>]{\fpeval{#1}}\x` is better. Since `\num` is `\protected`, it doesn't expand in an `\edef`.

Comment: @egreg, ok thanks. I didn't pay much attention to optimizing that. The same also with `\noexpand\numprint` as `\numprint` expands.

Answer (score 11):

As long as the expression is not too complex, we can use the LaTeX3 FPU to do the work here. I've gone for an approach where the input is 're-written' into the appropriate syntax: one could do that for the Lua-based answers given by others, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \printandcalc } { m }
  {
    #1 =
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
      \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
      \cs_set:Npx \__cs_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
      \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__cs_tmp:w
      \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } }
        { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
    \num [scientific-notation = true, round-mode = places]
      { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
}
\begin{document}
\[
N = \printandcalc{\frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to TeX.SE! There is whole discussion on doing [serious computations in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294239/121799). My answer is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294465/121799) and at best a starting point, which shows that it is indeed possible to do something along those lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294465/121799
\def\luaprint#1{\directlua{tex.print(#1)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  N = \frac{6.022\cdot10^{23}}{1.2\cdot10^{19}}
  =\luaprint{(1.932*10^6)*6.022*10^(23)/(197)}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that there are various possibilities to print these numbers in LateX. Unfortunately, I do not know too much on `luacode` but what I do know is that section 92 of the pgfmanual lists several possibilities to do that in Ti*k*Z/pgf.

Answer (score 9):

This answer is merely an extension of [@marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455000/5001). It uses (a) the `luacode` environment to define a Lua function in a way that allows the use of the `%` "magic" character and (b) the `\num` macro of the `siunitx` package, to prettify the output of the Lua calculations.

It's definitely *possible* to create a preprocessor-type function that captures and modifies all instances of `\frac{...}{...}`, `\log`, `\sin`, `\pi`, etc. so that the code can be parsed by Lua. (It has to be at the preprocessor stage, so that TeX will not try to act on `\frac`, `^`, etc.) One very important consideration is that TeX's grouping characters, `{` and `}`, will have to be replaced with `(` and `)`. Unless you need to perform lots and lots of formula evaluations in your document, it's almost certainly much quicker to perform the simplifications and adjustments "by hand".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,siunitx}
%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
function luaprint ( n )
  return tex.sprint ( string.format ( "%.3e" , n ) )
end
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code:
\def\luaprint#1{\num{\directlua{luaprint(#1)}}}

\begin{document}
\[
N = \frac{19.32\times1\times10^6\times6.023\times10^{23}}{197}
    =\luaprint{(19.32*1*10^6*6.023*10^(23))/197}
\]
\end{document}
```