# LaTeX calculator with variables and number substitution

Tags: calc

Is there a calculator with variables and number substitution with LaTeX syntax?

Here is an example:

1. First I set the variables:

- `m_\text{груза} = 5`
- `h = 2`
- `g = 9,81`

2. Next, I write the equation to be solved:

- `E_\text{п} = m_\text{груза} \cdot g \cdot h`

3. The output I want to get is as follows:

- `E_\text{п} = m_\text{груза} \cdot g \cdot h = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 9,81 = 98,1`

> Note. Please note that I use Cyrillic characters in the lower indices of the variables.

Comment: Unrelate. Please never use `_\text{...}` first of `\text` does not do what you think it does. Use `\textrm` (as I'm assuming those texts are not ascii), secondly it is a fluke that `_\text{...}` actually work and there is no guarantee that it will keep working. Please use `_{\textrm{...}|}`

Comment: @daleif I would say somehow the opposite. The macro `\text` as provided by `amstext` ( usually loaded via `amsmath`) is precisely done to render subscripts or superscript which are words or nouns in text mode, as they should be (using the surrounding text's font  which is not always Roman) but reduced I'm size as rear-ended by their position. Hence I would write `\( E_n = m_{\text{груза}} \cdot g \cdot h \)`.

Comment: Welcome on TeX.se!

Comment: @Jhor no, `\textit{ $x_{\text{is is upright}}$}` In most cases people expect the word index to be upright and it should be so one does not confuseit with mathematical indicies. And thus those texts should never be allowed to become italics.

Comment: @ daleif for sure! But what about if the text is in sffamiily ? Perhaps could I use a patch for `\text` to enforce '\textrm` in it? But in fact No! as it is also useful to write sentences containing inline math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perhaps not the expected answer, but if your paremeters are stored in macros, and you have a recent LaTeX kernel (or load the `xfp` package) you could use the latex3 fpu and write

```
\def\mгру{5}
\def\hh{2}
\def\ggrav{9.81}

$ E_n = m_{\text{груза}} \cdot g \cdot h$ \\
$= \mrpy \cdot \ggrav \cdot \hh$ \\ 
$=\fpeval{\mrpy*\ggrav*\hh}$
```

If the output of `\fpeval` doesn't fit your need in terms of formating, one can easily be formatted by using the `siunitx` or `numprint` packages.

In the same way, if, in the second line you want to print `\mryp` as `9,81` and not `9.81` you will use `numprint` to handle the decimal separarator.

What I do in such typical situatuon is definimg a macro which combines both `numprint`/`siunitx` and `\fpeval`, taking advantage of the expandability of the latter.

**Edit** : for the last point see  `\printandeval` in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455016/33514) and specially the `xfp+siunitx` answer. This explicits the use of `siunitx`'s `\num` macro (customize its options list, e.g. by  adding `output-decimal-marker = {,}`).

It also would enable to keep the `\cdot` if you want, by adding `\def\cdot{*}` as done for `\times`.

Comment: `$...$\\$...$`? Are you sure?

Comment: @egreg it was simply to split the line, without introducing a split or an align. Of course, I would never recoimmand nor use such a construct !

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a centralized variable definition factory.

With `\defvar` you define both the textual representation and the (numeric) value. The optional argument is for variables whose textual representation cannot be safely used, in the code below the example is `mgruza` (of course, you can choose whatever string you like).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defvar}{O{#2}mm}
 {% #1 = name, #2 = text, #3 = value
  \gusev_var_def:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\vval}{m}
 {% #1 = name
  \prop_item:Nn \g_gusev_var_prop { #1@value }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\vtext}{m}
 {% #1 = name
  \prop_item:Nn \g_gusev_var_prop { #1@text }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\numeval}{O{}m}
 {
  \num[#1]{\fpeval{#2}}
 }

\prop_new:N \g_gusev_var_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gusev_var_def:nnn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_gusev_var_prop { #1@text } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_gusev_var_prop { #1@value } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defvar[mgruza]{m_{\textup{груза}}}{5}
\defvar{h}{2}
\defvar{g}{9.81}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
E_{\textup{п}}
&= \vtext{mgruza} \cdot \vtext{g} \cdot \vtext{h} \\
&= \num{\vval{mgruza}} \cdot \num{\vval{g}} \cdot \num{\vval{h}} \\
&= \numeval{\vval{mgruza} * \vval{g} * \vval{h}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\numeval` command takes an optional argument just like `\num` to do local settings such as the rounding precision and so on (see the manual of `siunitx`).

I suggest *not* using `\text`, but `\textup`, because you don't want that the subscript is in italic if the context is so. Note also the additional braces.

One last *caveat*: always input the numeric value with a period for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use `fp` package**
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} % Кодировка для кириллицы
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % UTF-8 кодировка
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % Поддержка русского языка
\usepackage{fp}

 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for text in equations
\usepackage{pgfmath} % for calculations

% Define variables using newcommand
\newcommand{\mrus}{5}
\newcommand{\hrus}{2}
\newcommand{\grus}{9.81}

\begin{document}

% Calculate potential energy
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Erus}{\mrus * \grus * \hrus}

% Print the equation and result
\[ E_{\text{п}} = m_{\text{груза}} \cdot g \cdot h = \mrus \cdot \grus \cdot \hrus = \Erus \]

\end{document}
```

*In addition, please look at the example **1.2** [here](https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook)
Here I show how to create simple dynamic form for calculations*

Comment: Thiss code doesn’t use `fp`